# module.exports won't export object with function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, node-modules

I've made a ModulesManager to manage all my modules, so I don't have a huge list of requirements in the top of my "server.js", but every time I'm trying to access the manager's methods, my server crash and throw an error which is saying that my manager method isn't a function.

```
TypeError: moduleManager.sqlString is not a function
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here, this might be a stupid error, I've tried to look online for an answer but everyone is saying something different and nothing work.

Modules Manager (manager.js):

```
const sqlSetup = require("./sqlSetup.js");
const sqlSafeString = require("./sqlString.js");

function Manager(){
    this.sqlString = function(query){
        return sqlSafeString.getSqlSafeString(query);
    },
    this.sql = function(){
        return sqlSetup;
    }
}
module.exports = Manager;
```

Module SQL (sqlSetup.js):

```
const SqlString = require('sqlstring');

function getSqlSafeString(query){
    //format query to fit in MySQL
    var format = SqlString.escape(query);   
    return format;
}
module.exports = getSqlSafeString;
```

This is a test for my Travis build that I'm trying to make, the module manager path is good, the problem is really in the "ModuleManager.js" which I don't understand...

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = process.env.MOISTY;
const moduleManager = require("../modules/manager.js");
const assert = require("assert");

console.log("MAKE SURE MOISTY IS OFFLINE!");

client.login(token);

client.on('ready', () => {
    //confirm login
    console.log("MOISTY:200");

    //Assert
    assert.deepEqual(moduleManager.sqlString("sample text"), "sample test");

    //terminate the session
    process.exit();
});
```

I'm not very used to module exports, so this might be an easy question...

Comment: Are you sure that the error is still `TypeError: moduleManager.sqlString is not a function` after changing your code to `module.exports = new Manager();`? I'm pretty sure it is `TypeError:sqlSafeString.getSqlSafeString is not a function` now.

Comment: @t.niese you're right! is that because I always need to create the instance? This makes sense thanks!

Comment: No, I have explained both problems in my answer. Anyway, you should never update your answer to a new problem, otherwise all previous answers will become wrong.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I won't do that again!

Comment: And not add `[SOLVED]` to the title, accepting the answer that solves your problem is sufficient. I did a rollback to the point that matches the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes in your code.

`module.exports = getSqlSafeString;` sets the `export` to `getSqlSafeString`.

When you do `require("./sqlString.js")` you will get the value that was assigned to the `exports` so in your case the `getSqlSafeString`.

So if you want to access that function you would write:

```
const getSqlSafeString = require("./sqlString.js");
//...
return getSqlSafeString(query);`
```

`module.exports = Manager;` exports the function `Manager` but not an object of the type `Manager`, so `moduleManager.sqlString` would be equal to `Manager.sqlString`. If you only want to group the functions in one object, then using a constructor would not make much sense here anyway, so you should write it that way:

```
module.exports = {
    sqlString : function(query){
      return sqlSafeString.getSqlSafeString(query)
    },
    sql : function(){
      return sqlSetup
    }
};
```

If you really want to do create on Object of the type `Manager` then you need to write:

```
module.exports = new Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

For you to be able to `require` something from module A at module B, you have to export that something at module A. You export it assigning it to `module.exports`.

Yout problem is **you didn't export** the `Manager` at the Manager module.

You could simple export `Manager`, but, because you seem to be using an instance of `Manager`:

```
const moduleManager = require("../modules/manager.js");
...
moduleManager.sqlString("sample text")
```

Then you must export an instance. Add to `manager.js`:

```
module.exports = new Manager();
```

Comment: sorry I forgot one line in my post, I just edited it, but I'll try to add the new keyword and see if it works

Comment: Even with new keyword and "()" it doesn't work I still get the message I'll update the post

Comment: I just tried here, `module.exports = new Manager();` did work. You must have been doing something else.

Comment: yeah, I just didn't notice that the message has changed, look up t.neise commented that, but still thanks for helping!

Comment: Well, I didn't understand what you meant. But since it is now fixed, then problem solved! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the functions on an instance, ie `this.sqlString` is a property named `sqlString` on an instance of `Manager`. But you are not using `Manager` as a constructor, ie not doing `new Manager()` or in your case `new moduleManager()`

You can change your import code to like below

```
const moduleManager = new require("../modules/manager.js")();
```

Or change the export to:

```
module.exports = new Manager();
```

Then `moduleManager` will be an instance of `Manager` and will be able to use `moduleManager.sqlString`